# ASP.NET C# Login with Roles is not Redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a login module with roles. I have two tables Users and UserType.
The problem is after clicking the login it does not redirect to assigned pages, its still in the login page.
Here's the Login.cs code

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = @"SELECT u.UserID, u.Username, u.Password, t.UserType FROM Users u INNER JOIN UserType t ON t.TypeID = u.TypeID WHERE Username=@Username AND Username=@Username";
        //string query = @"SELECT UserID, Username, Password, TypeID FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username AND Username=@Username";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Session["UserID"] = dr["UserID"].ToString();

                    }
                    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        string Utype;
                        Utype = dt.Rows.ToString().Trim();
                        if (Utype == "HR Admin")
                        {
                            Session["Username"] = txtUsername.Text;
                            Response.Redirect("~/Administrator/Home.aspx");
                        }
                        if (Utype == "Employee")
                        {
                            Session["Username"] = txtUsername.Text;
                            Response.Redirect("~/HrPortal/Home.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    error.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dt.Rows.Count` will always be zero because you never put anything into it.

Comment: Also the correct way of getting uType is - dr["UserType"].ToString();..instead of dt.Rows.ToString().Trim();

Comment: You don't need the DataTable just read everything from the data reader. Also, only select those columns which you need, i.e. you do not need Password column. Put `Session["Username"]` outside the if condition and only keep the redirect within the condition.

Comment: @CodingYoshi thank you so much bro it worked!